# CSS sheet not affecting my layout?

Tags: css

I have an asp.net website where I'm using stylesheets.  Problem is, when I went in to make some changes to the stylesheets, they don't seem be affecting the layout of the pages.  On a whim, I commented out every line in the stylesheet, and my layout looks the same!

I do have the style sheet linked into my masterpage, and the layout looks (mostly) like what I want.  What can cause this behavior and how can I try to correct?

EDIT: My import link looks like this:

```
<link href="NCLWebStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Browser caching? Hit CTRL+F5 to find out.

Comment: Could still be a cache problem with the CSS file. Try changing the file name to `NCLWebStyle.css?1`

Comment: @MAW74656: I don't see how that experiment would rule out the caching hypothesis.

Comment: is the `css` file in the same folder as the current page you are viewing ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli -Its in the same folder as the master page which all my pages use.

Comment: @MAW, if you master pages is being used from within subfolders/routing of your site it will not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, check out the Firebug add in-  this will let you inspect the page as it is loaded and rendered in the browser, and you can see exactly what CSS rules are being applied to each element in your page, what the inheritance of each attribute is - it is invaluable as a web design tool

Comment: -I do have firefox, do you know of any good tutorials for Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for debugging:

1. Check spelling
2. Check page errors (404s in particular)
3. Check inline styles
4. Check for `!important`
5. Manually clear your cache (Temporary internet files in IE)

Comment: -Can you expand on the !important note?

Comment: `!important` is the devil. It basically pushes the rule on which it's applied to the top of the precedence order. So, a rule with `!important` will override any rule against which it would compete. [Here's some w3c documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Load the site in Firefox and check the Net tab to make sure the style sheet is loading. From your link it looks like the style sheet is inside the same folder as the page. If it is not then the path may need to be revised. If it is not that is the problem; otherwise it may be some of your selectors. The easy way to diagnose that is to change some thing simple like:

```
body { background: red; }
```

That will set the background to red, so it should be obvious if it loads. If it does then the selectors are off or it could be that the styles you are setting up are being overwritten. Use Firebug to select the elements and see if the styles are being over written. If the styles you wrote have a strike through them then they are being overwritten by a more specific style or some thing that was loaded later. Check to see where it is loading the styles it is using from.

Also, the styles could be messed up by the `!important` tag, which prevents any further styles from over writing the values it sets.

Comment: -I wasn't aware of the !important tag, so I definetly haven't used it.  I'll take a look at Firebug.  Know of any good video tutorials for it?

Answer (score 0):

What does your link syntax look like?

i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />`

Comment: Try changing the href to "./NCLWebStyle.css"